# Metamask tries to connect when it shouldn't

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, dapp-debugging

Brief explanation: I tried to embed some interactivity to a website using plain js/html. I deploy a smart contract using hardhat-deploy plug-in (my contract gets deployed when i spin up the hardhat node) and then try to tinker with my site using Metamask and test accounts that hardhat gives you.
Here's my BaseContract instance:

```js
const account0 = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80"; // Hardhat account
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account0, provider);
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
```

For some reasons, whenever it comes to execute something related to calling read functions using that BaseContract my Metamask pops up and tries to connect. Using a debugger, i set some breakpoints, and when it tries to execute this line here:

```js
const votingTime = await elections.getVotingTime();
// getVotingTime is a 'read' method
```

All of a sudden, Metamask pops up and tries to connect. So i wonder, how to fix it?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code of `getVotingTime`?

Comment: `function getVotingTime() public pure returns (uint256) { return (VOTING_TIME);}`, where VOTING_TIME is a constant

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the problem! Here's what i changed:

Code before:

```js
const account0 = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80";
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/", 31337);
const userProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
const userSigner = await userProvider.getSigner();
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account0, provider);
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
```

and after:

```js
const account0 = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80";
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/", 31337);
// const userProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
// const userSigner = await userProvider.getSigner();
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account0, provider);
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer); // works fine with the signer instead of provider btw

let userSigner;
```

I populate `userSigner` variable later on when it comes to using `eth_requestAcounts` method:

```js
// this happens inside of my custom `connect()` function
...
userAccount = (await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }))[0];
const userProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
userSigner = await userProvider.getSigner();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***read-only static*** methods, the contract should be instantiated by passing a `provider` instead of a `signer`.

Because if you pass the `signer`, Metamask will pop up each time unless you're connected already, or, in some cases, it'll pop up every time just to confirm the transaction.

It's a known behavior explained here: (**https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-connect**).

**To call static methods, consider instantiating the contract like this instead:**

```js
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
```

See this example:

```js
// A Human-Readable ABI; for interacting with the contract, we
// must include any fragment we wish to use
const abi = [
    // Read-Only Functions
    "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
    "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
    "function symbol() view returns (string)",

    // Authenticated Functions
    "function transfer(address to, uint amount) returns (bool)",

    // Events
    "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)"
];

// This can be an address or an ENS name
const address = "0x70ff5c5B1Ad0533eAA5489e0D5Ea01485d530674";

// Read-Only; By connecting to a Provider, allows:
// - Any constant function
// - Querying Filters
// - Populating Unsigned Transactions for non-constant methods
// - Estimating Gas for non-constant (as an anonymous sender)
// - Static Calling non-constant methods (as anonymous sender)
const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);

// Read-Write; By connecting to a Signer, allows:
// - Everything from Read-Only (except as Signer, not anonymous)
// - Sending transactions for non-constant functions
const erc20_rw = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);
```

If you need both read and write access, but you don't want to overwhelm the UX with requesting Metamask to connect each time, you can consider doing something like this:

1. Use `const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);` for ***read-only*** methods;
2. Use `const electionsMutable = elections.connect(signer);` for ***write*** methods;

Comment: That doesn't work for me though. Strangely enough, my Metamask pops up even when it comes to this line: `const userSigner = await userProvider.getSigner();`, where userProvider is `const userProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);`

Comment: Hmm, and does that behavior repeat again when you do accept the request to connect Metamask to your website?

Comment: Well, problem actually disappears as fast as connect to Metamask. What would such strange behavior mean? I tried to delete Metamask's cache and to clear the activity tab, neither helped

Comment: It must be related to this thing: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/4431#issuecomment-1941912038

Metamask popping up is an expected behavior for `const userSigner = await userProvider.getSigner();`, however it's odd that it pops up when you call static methods.